# Make excel do multiplication across horizontal cells with stacked numbers within cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I want to make excel automatically multiply the hourly rate by the hours done by person A and B up to Z to create the column D total dollars but my data is formatted this way.

How do I make excel do this without changing my formatting and having to take out a calculator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiply two columns and add the products for a range of rows or cells?](https://superuser.com/questions/1215456/multiply-two-columns-and-add-the-products-for-a-range-of-rows-or-cells)

Comment: Check the link above solves the issue !

Comment: Do you have cells merged for person A & person B? If yes, no good way for that with formulas

Comment: @KennethL ::No.

Comment: @MátéJuhász: false!

Comment: @Germania, have you checked if my answer is helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, when entering hourly rate ($) and hourly rate ($) data, add a space " " after the first line of data.
For example, "930 " and "3.5 ", you maybe could try this:

```
=LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1)*LEFT(C2,FIND(" ",C2)-1)+RIGHT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1)*RIGHT(C2,FIND(" ",C2)-1)
```

[image]

In addition, in Excel, it is recommended to place only one data in a cell, which is extremely simple.
[image]

---

---

**Update：**
No need to do anything else, try this:

```
=LEFT(B15,FIND(CHAR(10),B15)-1)*LEFT(C15,FIND(CHAR(10),C15)-1)+RIGHT(B15,FIND(CHAR(10),B15)-1)*RIGHT(C15,FIND(CHAR(10),C15)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: You could replace `" "` with `CHAR(10)` to find the new line character.

Comment: Hi @Darren Bartrup-Cook, thanks for very useful information. Hi Germania, I have updated my answer, please check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If it looks like that, it's formatted as text. The first step should be to process it into a sensible data format, with one number per cell.

You could do it, using value and len, but it would be incredibly contorted and not the best use of your time.

If it's a one off clean, drop raw values into word, take off the """ and you can drop it back in. If it's coming in to you like this routinely, you'll need to make use of VBA I'd suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore column A as it's the product of columns B & C you're after.

Split those columns into an array using `FILTERXML` (an example of splitting column B):
`=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")`.

You can then use `SUMPRODUCT` on the result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(C2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]